# Creating with Visual Studio 2010 for older .net frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks, .net-4.0

I'm creating some simple apps with Visual Studio 2010 (C#), and I noticed that they require .net framework 4 on the client computers for working...

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2010 to create apps that don't need .net framework 4? I want them to run on normal PCs without the users to need to install anything.

Cheers all,

Answer (score 4):

Right-click project in Solution Explorer and select Properites and change Target framework. What version you should choose depends of what you are using from Framewok, but 2.0 should be okay for most XP machines and is pretty powerful. Just test if your app works with 2.0.

If you want your apps work even in Windows 95 and without extra downloads, consider Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

You can select other versions of the .NET Framework when creating a new Project. You can choose from version 4.0, 3.5, 3.0 and 2.0. You can get 1.1 from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569264)

Answer (score 2):

Available from [statowl](http://www.statowl.com/microsoft_dotnet.php), current for March 2011.  Kinda crappy that they don't break down between 3.0 and 3.5 SP1:

[image]

Comment: .NET Framework 3.x uses same runtime as 2, so app for 2 can run on machines with 3.x. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx    .NET Framewok 4 uses new runtime but still is backward-compatible with 2 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx